# For Loop over data frame, using dplyr results in error

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a, simplified, a data frame with 71 columns and N rows. What I want to get is a frequency table of the values in the first column based on all other columns (all other columns have dummies). Simplified (with only 4 columns) this would be like that:

```
df <- data.frame(sample(1:8,20,replace=T),sample(0:1,20,replace = T),sample(0:1,20,replace = T),sample(0:1,20,replace = T))
```

I have tried this for loop with dplyr (where x is the first column with the 8 different values), and it only works for the first 10 or 11 columns without problems, but after then it only generates NA's and returns the error:

```
freq_df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=8, ncol=71))
for (i in 2:71){
  freq_df[,i] <- df %>%
    filter(df[i]==1) %>%
    count(x) %>%
    select(n)
}       

in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(n = c(3L, 5L, 8L,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 7 rows, need 8
```

Anyone knows why R returns this error? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is because not all first column values will occur where other columns are 1. You have 8 unique values in the first column, maybe you have 7 when you filter on the 11th column == 1. So the results can have different lengths, which is a problem.

Try this instead, I think it's what you're trying to do. (If not, please clarify your goal by showing the expected output.)

```
names(df) = paste0("V", 1:4)
df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), sum, .names = "{.col}_count"))
#      V1 V2_count V3_count V4_count
#   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
# 1     1        1        0        1
# 2     2        2        1        2
# 3     3        3        3        2
# 4     4        0        0        0
# 5     5        0        0        0
# 6     6        3        1        2
# 7     7        3        1        1
# 8     8        1        1        0
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do

```
names(df) <- paste0("V", 1:4)
out <- aggregate(.~ V1, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
names(out)[-1] <- paste0(names(out)[-1], "_count")
```